# Click on dynamically added element fires 2 click events

Tags: jquery, html, ajax, jquery-selectors, click

On my site, users can edit previously added items by clicking on them, then ajax loads exact same elements (same id and class) with different content accordingly information in database into a 'edit section'.

After user has clicked on one item and tries to edit another, clicking on element in 'edit section' fires 2 click events. The problem is that clicking on one specific element loads another information with ajax, so I get double results

I have made that after user clicks on another item, previous 'edit section' will be removed with jQuery function remove(), but it doesn't solve the problem.

**Edit:**

I think I found the problem, but I cant come up with good solution. If user clicks on item to edit it, ajax loads HTML and some JS what those HTML elements need, but I cant remove JS from success function, because JS doesn't work on items, what are loaded after page is loaded.

Comment: please share the element creation and event registration code

Comment: can you please share your code and HTML..?

Answer (score 0):

Sharing your code will provide us more information. Anyway most of the times your events fires multiple times the problem is you are registering the same event multiple times.

One aproach to avoid this, just in case you need your event be fired only one time is using "one" function instead of "on" function. Or "unbind" registered events.